# There are no data sources to show for the selected project

Tags: datagridview, visual-c++-2019

I am currently experiencing the following problem.

Current configuration:

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.8.0 Preview 3.2

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.7.5

(Note: The problem occurs in both the above versions.)

Microsoft Visual C++ 2019 (00435-60000-00000-AA566)

Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.8.03752

Microsoft Windows 10 Pro Build 18363

SQL Server Data Tools (16.0.62009.04150)

VS Workload: Desktop development with C++

Problem description:

I place a dataGridView component on a form. When I try to add a data source to the dataGridView, the option to “Add New Data Source” is greyed out.

Screenshots are available below:

[There are no data sources to show for the selected project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eh85G.png)

[No Data Sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtlMT.png)

Note: I can successfully add a data connection to a local SQL Express instance via Data Connections in Server Explorer.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled VS Community 2019 version 16.7.5 several times. I currently use the VS Community 2019 Preview version 16.8.0 – same scenario and configuration. Same problem occurs.

I have installed, uninstalled and reinstalled on a second computer as well. Same problem occurs.

Question:

How do I get the "Add New Data Sources" button to become active (so I can select it to add a data source)?

Your guidance and assistance are much appreciated (as well as your valuable time).

Thank you.